# Matching div's using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need help with matching two div's that use onclick and to disappear when they match.

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src='move.js'></script>
            <link href='style.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='holder'>
                <div class='box logo0' id='bo1' ></div>
                <div class='box logo1' id='bo2'></div>
                <div class='box logo2' id='bo3'></div>
                <div class='box logo3' id='bo4'></div>
                <div class='box logo4' id='bo5'></div>
                <div class='box logo5' id='bo6'></div>
            </div>


        </audio>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to match `div id="bo3"` and `div id="bo4"`

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv('#bo1');
    animateDiv('#bo2');
    animateDiv('#bo3');
    animateDiv('#bo4');
       $('#bo1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('logo0 down0');
    });
        $('#bo2').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('logo1 down1');
    });
        $('#bo3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('logo2 down2');
    });
    $('#bo4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('logo3 down3');
    });
});


function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(divtag){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(divtag).offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $(divtag).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv(divtag);        
    });
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
function changeImage(ImageID,ImageFileName)
{
document.getElementById(ImageID).src = ImageFileName;
}
```

As you can see when you click them, they swap images to the other image that has a highlight(added by photoshop). So I am making a game that you have to match the image by logo and weapon. So for instance, I have the halo logo and you have to match the weapon that belongs to the game. So I only have the halo sword so far because I want to match one weapon and logo before adding more.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want this to be a sort of game where you click one box, which then becomes highlighted, and the goal is to click its match.  If the match is clicked, the pair disappears, if a non-matching box is clicked, both become de-highlighted, ready for the next try.

The first thing you'll need is a way to determine whether and which box is already selected.  This is most simply done by adding an additional class to your existing toggle statement like:
`$(this).toggleClass('logo2 down2 selected');` using the same name for all boxes.  You can then find the selected box with:

```
var selected = $("div.box.selected");
```

You will also need a way to programmatically determine which items match.  This could be a mapping of classnames in an array provided by your server, a string match on a portion the image url, hardcoded match in the click function, or many other options.

Just by way of example, if `bo3` will always match `bo4`, you could use the following for the click handler:

```
$('#bo3').click(function(){
    // find out if any boxes are selected
    var selected = $("div.box.selected");
    if (selected.length) > 0 {
      // if the selected box is our match, add the matched class
      // your stylesheet can determine matched means invisible, special location, whatever
      if (selected.first().attr("id") == "bo4" {
        $("#bo3,#bo4").removeClass("selected").addClass("matched");
      } elseif (selected.first().attr("id") == "bo3" {
        // this element got re-clicked, just deselect
        $(this).toggleClass('logo2 down2 selected');
      } else {
        // if we didn't match, send the click event to whatever was selected to deselect it
        selected.click();
      }
    } else {
        // if nothing else was selected, this element should toggle.
        $(this).toggleClass('logo2 down2 selected');
    }
});

// essentially the same for the matching box
$('#bo4').click(function(){
    var selected = $("div.box.selected");
    if (selected.length) > 0 {
      if (selected.first().attr("id") == "bo3" {
        $("#bo3,#bo4").removeClass("selected").addClass("matched");
      } elseif (selected.first().attr("id") == "bo4" {
        $(this).toggleClass('logo3 down3 selected');
      } else {
        selected.click();
      }
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('logo3 down3 selected');
    }
});
```

much of this could be defined in a function that is called by the click handlers to reduce code duplication, but I'll leave that up to you.